# Converting a sparse R integer dgCMatrix to a corresponding sparse R rank dgCMatrix

Tags: r, memory, sparse-matrix, rank

This another question about efficient handling of a large `R` sparse `Matrix` (`dgCMatrix`):

I would like to convert my existing ~15,000 x ~90,000 `dgCMatrix` to a corresponding rank `dgCMatrix`, where rank means that each column assigns a rank to each of its rows.

Doing it the `apply` way would be:

```
rank.mat <- apply(mat, 2, function(i) dplyr::dense_rank(i))-1
```

Such that zero values will get rank `0` and the smallest nonzero element in a column get a rank of `1`.

Unfortunately, this is RAM intensive and on my mac gives me this error:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

And these warnings:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In asMethod(object) :
  sparse->dense coercion: allocating vector of size 9.2 GiB
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: So would the smallest nonzero element in a column get a rank of `1`?

Comment: Yes. I updated it in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function to perform the column-wise rankings:

```
f <- function(m) {
  addx <- diff(range(m@x))*1.01
  d <- diff(m@p)
  m@x <- rank(rep(addx*(1:ncol(m)), d) + m@x) - rep(m@p[-length(m@p)], d)
  m
}
```

The idea is for each `x`, add a number larger than the difference of the range of `x` values (`diff(range(m@x))*1.01`) multiplied by the column number. Each of the resulting values will be smaller than any other value in a column further to the right, so `rank` will preserve the column ordering. After `rank` is performed on all these values at once, subtract from each rank the number of nonzero values in columns to the left (`rep(m@p[-length(m@p)], d)`) to get the in-column rank.

Two potential problems with this approach are overflow if the range of values is too close to `.Machine$double.xmax` and precision if the magnitude of the values differs greatly between columns. A faster and simpler alternative that does not have these problems is `data.table::frank`, which will accept a list of vectors and prioritize the ranking based on the list ordering. The first vector will be the column number of each `x` value, and the second vector will be the `x` values. As with the first solution, subtract from each rank the number of nonzero values in columns to the left.

```
library(data.table)

f2 <- function(m) {
  d <- diff(m@p)
  m@x <- frank(list(rep(1:ncol(m), d), m@x)) - rep(m@p[-length(m@p)], d)
  m
}
```

Testing on an example matrix.

```
library(Matrix)

set.seed(417571134)
m <- 15e3L # rows
n <- 9e4L  # columns
x <- 15e5L # approximate number of elements

mat <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(sample(m, x - 1L, 1), m),
  j = c(sample(n, x - 1L, 1), n),
  x = runif(x)
)

rank.mat <- f(mat)
rank.mat2 <- f2(mat)
```

Check the results of the first column:

```
i <- mat@i[1:mat@p[2]] + 1L
mat[i, 1]
#>  [1] 0.35989249 0.42091241 0.76024738 0.91255329 0.34046934 0.83639504
#>  [7] 0.90911125 0.36855899 0.08246935 0.94288443 0.88631741
rank.mat[i, 1]
#>  [1]  3  5  6 10  2  7  9  4  1 11  8
rank.mat2[i, 1]
#>  [1]  3  5  6 10  2  7  9  4  1 11  8
```

Check the results of the tenth column:

```
i <- mat@i[(mat@p[10] + 1):mat@p[11]] + 1L
mat[i, 10]
#>  [1] 0.514592407 0.226479125 0.860830711 0.144284130 0.321209116 0.382332153
#>  [7] 0.640740419 0.182481764 0.265399369 0.903738448 0.263895980 0.352454961
#> [13] 0.489450124 0.563764343 0.033616684 0.920258529 0.555317195 0.118023316
#> [19] 0.622369254 0.379063432 0.452010235 0.743245327 0.634726081 0.645606269
#> [25] 0.936185833 0.009523308 0.740878726
rank.mat[i, 10]
#>  [1] 15  6 24  4  9 12 20  5  8 25  7 10 14 17  2 26 16  3 18 11 13 23 19 21 27
#> [26]  1 22
rank.mat2[i, 10]
#>  [1] 15  6 24  4  9 12 20  5  8 25  7 10 14 17  2 26 16  3 18 11 13 23 19 21 27
#> [26]  1 22
```

Timing the two solutions:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f = f(mat),
  f2 = f2(mat),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>     f 110.27932 117.5476 136.3322 121.4216 133.6265 315.6330   100
#>    f2  85.10733 106.4986 127.6798 112.4893 122.6948 300.2763   100
```